# JS/Angular - how to separate loading spinners for multiple boxes at webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, loader

I have webpage that is some kind of a dashboard with different boxes. In every box I'm getting data from database - when data is loading I want to show spinner. To load data I have one method:

```
loadElements() {
    this.name = this.overviewService.getName();
    this.systemsResult = this.systemService.getSystemsNumber(this.databaseId, this.formatDate(this.dateFrom), this.formatDate(this.dateTo));
    this.countCallsResult = this.statisticService.getCallsNumber(this.databaseId, this.formatDate(this.dateFrom), this.formatDate(this.dateTo));
    this.countConnectionResult = this.connectionService.getConnectionsNumber(this.databaseId, this.formatDate(this.dateFrom), this.formatDate(this.dateTo));
    this.dataVolumeResult = this.statisticService.getDataVolume(this.databaseId, this.formatDate(this.dateFrom), this.formatDate(this.dateTo));
    this.systemsInfo = this.overviewService.getSystemsInfo();
```

And I'm calling this at NgOnInit. I want to separate spinners becouse some results I can get faster then the others. I know how to show spinners that dissaper at the same time but I don't know how to separate them. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can show/hide your different spinners for their corresponding data by using `*ngIf` directive sepreatly for different data. Consider following scenario and make changes in your file accordingly.

**.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="!name; else showName">
 <app-spinner></app-spinner>
</div>
<ng-template #showName>{{name}}</ng-template>

<div *ngIf="!systemsInfo; else showSystemsInfo">
 <app-spinner></app-spinner>
</div>
<ng-template #showSystemsInfo >{{systemInfo}}</ng-template>
```

**.component.ts**

```
name : any;
systemsInfo : any;

ngOnInit(){
 this.loadData()
}

loadData(){
  this.name = this.overviewService.getName();
  this.systemsInfo = this.overviewService.getSystemsInfo();
  // rest of data
}
```

Comment: I did that just like You said, but when for example I set !systemsInfo then I always get 'else' template and number of system is 0, and after retrive data then is growing to number from database. When I set to ngIf="systemsInfo" I see that spinner works fine so the problem is method of loading data I think...